# DB2 TRANSLATE for Question Mark in Data

Tags: db2, db2-400

I have a statement on DB2 using the TRANSLATE function:

```
 ,TRANSLATE( FIELD1, ' ',  x'042021222324282A3638FF') FIELD1A
```

How to I modify the statement for a question mark character in data

Thank you.

Comment: What is the hexadecimal representation of a question mark symbol in your code page?

Comment: Try `TRANSLATE( FIELD1, ' ',  x'6F042021222324282A3638FF')` since `VALUES HEX('?')` returns `6F`.

Answer (score 0):

ihope that i understood youright. You want to replace a '?' by ' ' is that true? in this case translate works like this:

```sql
VALUES translate('sdnfojs?sdmf', ' ', x'6F'),
       translate('sdnfojs?sdmf', ' ', '?');
--result: 'sdnfojs sdmf'
```